# Cómo personalizar barra titulo Winform C# y desplegar listado de opciones(restaurar, minimizar,cerrar y más)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .netframework

Estoy queriendo crear un formulario base con barra de titulo personalizada.

Lo que intenté es ocultar el ControlBox de Form pero al hacer eso tendría que crear los elementos y los eventos de RESTAURAR, MAXIMIZAR Y CERRAR. Además no puedo ejecutar el evento alt+space que permite desplegar las opciones de barra de titulo.

[image: Formulario de mi proyecto]

Así es como está mi formulario por el momento con opción de cerrar. Pero no puedo desplegar como la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así mismo agregar más opciones personalizadas a esa lista.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ok.. y cual es el problema?? winforms no tiene ese tipo de barras.. en wpf estas mas cerca pero igual tampoco.. vas a tener que hacer todo de cero...

Comment: coloca 3 botones con codigo para minimizar, cerrar, maximizar. Para el menu usa:   private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
           //muestra aqui un contextmenu personalizado por ejemplo
        }
    }